# Opacity in Fodor's computational theory of mind

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

I don't understand what *opaque construals* are, nor what *opaque taxonomies* are. What does he mean by opaque, and how are opaque construals different from transparent construals?

Comment: Maybe you could provide some context? Since my pal Steven Fodor found your question opaque.

Comment: Welcome to philosophy stack exchange.  We have a very useful help page https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help, which includes advice on how to write a good question.  Your question lacks context of how Fodor uses these terms, nor any indication of where you looked for understanding of Fodor's usage, or why you are confused by them.  Adding more content to your question would make any answer far more useful.